# Git permission to Username2/demo-repo2 denied to Username1

Tags: git, github

I changed my github account. I am now facing issues with respect to push.
I am able to clone a repo though. (I am a beginner to git)

When I change a file and do:
`git push origin master`, I get the following error:
`ERROR: Permission to AeroCouncillor/demo-repo2.git denied to atharvaaalok.`

atharvaaalok was my previous username, I have changed to AeroCouncillor now.

**I have already tried:**

```
git config --global user.name "AeroCouncillor"
git config --global user.email "required_email@XYZ.com"
```

But I still get the same error as before.

I followed another answer here on SO that told to delete git entry on Windows Credential Manager.
After that I created another entry as follows:

New entry on Windows Credential Manager

[image: 1]

used this as the Internet field and used:
Username: AeroCouncillor
Password: MyPassword

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by removing SSH keys.
Not sure, but I believe when I was trying `git push` it was looking for git ssh keys for connecting but the key it was using was that for the older account.

So I moved all keys to a sub folder then followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISeXMoEcG8Q&ab_channel=MaximOrlov) to create a new SSH key and add it to github (also deleted the older SSH key on github).

Now it works!